# MS Graph API | Error on content convert from xlsx to pdf

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft365, excel-365

I attempted an API call that converts the XLSX to PDF using the following endpoint

> GET /me/drive/items/{item-id}/content?format={format}

**Excel.xlsx**

1. Has 5 worksheets ['**Sheet1**', '**ワークシート**', '**,..&^&^(^(%^$%#$@@((&&)**']
2. Sheet1 is blank
3. ワークシート is filled from A1 to AZ360
4. Last sheet is blank

I got the following **ERROR** response for Excel.xlsx

```
{
    code: 'notSupported',
    message: 'Error from Office Service. Url=https://excelcs.officeapps.live.com/document/export/pdf HttpCode=UnsupportedMediaType cert=subject:;thumbprint: ResponseHeaders=X-ErrorCode: XLSPageLimitExceeded\r\n' +
      'X-ErrorCategory: NotSupported\r\n' +
      'X-IsRetriable: False\r\n' +
      'X-ClientCorrelationId: XXXXX-5a67-XXXXX-9060-XXXXXXXXXXXXX\r\n' +
      'X-ServiceCorrelationId: XXXXX-5a67-XXXXX-9060-XXXXXXXXXXXXX\r\n' +
      'X-ConversionTimeInMs: 687.5017\r\n' +
      'X-FileDownloadTimeInMs: 124.994\r\n' +
      'Cache-Control: private\r\n' +
      'Date: Mon, 23 Nov 2020 14:11:28 GMT\r\n' +
      'Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0\r\n' +
      'X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319\r\n' +
      'X-Powered-By: ASP.NET\r\n',
    innererror: { code: 'invalidFileFormat' }
}
```

**Questions**:

What is the real cause?

Is there a limitation for the above actions w.r.t to the following?

- file size
- number of rows
- number of columns
- number of cells
- number of sheets in that excel
- Anything I missed

Comment: Please try creating a simple excel file, put some data in it and then try using this call to convert it to PDF and see the difference.

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity I did and I got the error mentioned in the question above.

Comment: I have tried to repro your issue but I didn't get any issue. Could you please just add one single text record in sheet1 and another single text record in other worksheet and then try to convert to PDF data.